# How to get all id printed in list python

Tags: python-3.x

i want to get details of `id` in `payload`

```
payload = [
    {
    'id': 'Room1', 
            'temperature': 
                {
                  'value': '10', 
                  'type': 'Number'
                }, 
            'pressure':
        {
            'value': '12', 
            'type': 'Number'
            
        }, 
            'type': 'Room', 
            'time_index': '2020-08-19T11:36:47.370234'
    },
    {
   'id': 'Room2', 
        'temperature':
            {'value': '10', 
            'type': 'Number'
            }, 
        'pressure':
            {'value': '12', 
            'type': 'Number'
            }, 
            'type': 'Room', 
            'time_index': '2020-08-19T11:36:47.370586'
        
    }
            ]
```

Here i want to get `id: Room1,Room2` so i tried,

```
entity_id = payload.get('id',None) ----> getting output as Room2
print (entity_id)
```

So, when i am using list with index in above case like this: `entity_id = payload[0].get('id',None)` i am getting value of id as : `Room1` and for `entity_id = payload[1].get('id',None)` `Room2`

How can i get all values of `payload` `id` like `id at 0 index` and further on all values of id to get printed...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using a for loop to go over every element and get each id? Also, `payload.get('id',None)` should give you an error; `payload` is an list and doesn't have `get`

Comment: No i haven't  tried loop yet. New to python so dont know to use it exact for this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your expected output,

`id: Room1,Room2`,

then using list comprehension;

`print("id:", ", ".join(p.get(id, None) for p  in payload))`